# Selection bias?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, bias

1. Selection bias is defined as $E[y_{i0}|D=1]-E[y_{i0} |D=0]$. Calculate this.

I think I'm overcomplicating this in my head but do I just take the averages and subtract?
[image]

Comment: Please add the self-study tag for homework questions.  The Term $E[y_{i0}|D=1]$ translates to The expected value (or average) of the $y_{i0}$ values given $D=1$ (or when $D=1$).  You can probably figure it out from that hint.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to make some assumptions about your notation; namely, that it's standard notation for the Rubin potential outcomes framework [1]. To make this clear, I'm going to assume that $D$ is some binary treatment variable, where $D = 1$ indicates receiving the treatment and $D = 0$ indicates receiving the control. $y_i$ is the observed outcome for individual $i$, $y_{i1}$ is the outcome they would have had if they received the treatment, and $y_{i0}$ is the outcome they would have had if they received the control.

The expression $\mathbb{E}[y_{i0} | D = 1]$ is the expected outcome among individuals who actually received the treatment, had they instead been given the control. You can calculate this in your example by taking the average $y_{i0}$ among people with treatment status $D = 1$. The expression $\mathbb{E}[y_{i0} | D = 0]$ has a similar interpretation, and you can calculate it by the average $y_{i0}$ among people with treatment status $D = 0$. Then you simply take the difference.

The reason this is being called "selection bias" is because, if the difference $\mathbb{E}[y_{i0} | D = 1] - \mathbb{E}[y_{i0} | D = 0]$ is non-zero, then people who receive the treatment differ systematically from those who didn't. This is going to invalidate the so-called "ignorability" assumption.

[1] Imbens, G., & Rubin, D. (2015). *Causal Inference for Statistics, Social, and Biomedical Sciences: An Introduction.* Cambridge: Cambridge University Press. doi:10.1017/CBO9781139025751